# How to find minimum value on range of cells that are greater than 1 in excel?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a range of cells (AD2:AH29), and I want to find the minimum value for these cells. However, I only want to consider cells for which the value is greater than 1.

I tried using the following but I can't quite get the formula right, since I don't know how to tell excel to only consider the cells where the value is greater than 1:

```
MIN(IF(">1"),AD2:AH29)

MIN(IF(">1",AD2:AH29))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(AD2:AH29>1,AD2:AH29))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

OR

You can use AGGREGATE() and avoid the necessity of using Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,AD2:AH29/(AD2:AH29>1),1)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that AGGREGATE command be the following instead =AGGREGATE(5,6,AD2:AH29/(AD2:AH29>1),1), because 15 corresponds to the SMALL function which is the 2nd smallest value? 5 corresponds to the min function. See here: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/aggregate.php

Comment: @Veridian the `1` as the last criterion make is look for the first smallest value. and you can't use the validation of the denominator with the min function.  So no it needs to use the small function.